# How to delete temporal documents from MarkLogic database physically?

Tags: nosql, marklogic, marklogic-9, temporal-database, bi-temporal

I came across the temporal function "**[temporal.documentDelete](https://docs.marklogic.com/temporal.documentDelete)**" which "logically deletes" temporal documents in a MarkLogic database hence removing it from the latest collection. But the document is still not physically deleted from MarkLogic database. You can still retrieve the deleted documents using its URI.

Is there any way, where I can as well physically delete the temporal documents ingested into my MarkLogic database?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`temporal.documentWipe`](https://docs.marklogic.com/temporal.documentWipe), but bear in mind that it will wipe all versions of that document. You would basically be rewriting history, which is against the nature of temporal.

Also note that you can only wipe documents whose protection has expired. You protect temporal documents using [`temporal.documentProtect`](https://docs.marklogic.com/temporal.documentProtect).

More notes on deleting and wiping temporal documents can be found in the Temporal Guide:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/temporal/managing#id_10558

HTH!